# Google Test: Typelist of cartesian product of template template with a template

Tags: c++, googletest

Suppose I have two classes accepting each one template argument:

```
template <typename T> class A { };
template <typename T> class B { };
```

I want to run google Tests for `A<int>`, `A<double>`, `A<float>` and `B<int>`, `B<double>`, `B<float>`, i.e. the cartesian product `[A, B]` x `[int, double, float]`. How can I automatically generate a google test `testing::Types` object with all these combinations?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with parameter pack:

```
template <typename T> class A { public: void DoesBlah() { std::cout << "A:" << T(); } };
template <typename T> class B { public: void DoesBlah() { std::cout << "B:" << T(); } };

template <typename T>
class FooTest : public ::testing::Test {
};

template <typename T>
T& TestObj(T& o) {
    o.DoesBlah();
    return o;
}

template <typename... Ts>
void param_divider(Ts&... obj) {}

template <typename... Ts>
void foreachobj(Ts&... obj)
{
    param_divider(TestObj(obj)...);
}

typedef ::testing::Types<int, double, float>  MyTypes;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(FooTest, MyTypes);
TYPED_TEST(FooTest, Test) {
    foreachobj(A<TypeParam>(), B<TypeParam>());
}
```